# How to create a calendar based on data stored in SQL Server?`

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to create a employee schedule web app using the following code. I am storing the shift details in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shift] 
(
    [Shift_Id]    INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Start_Time]  DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [End_Time]    DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [Job_Type]    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Employee_Id] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Available]   INT          NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY ([Employee_Id]) 
         REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Employee_Id]) 
         ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

At the moment, I am displaying each employee's existing shifts using the following code:

```
private void bindRepeater()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Shift WHERE Employee_Id=@Id", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 
                ddlEmployee.SelectedValue);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                repMyShifts.DataSource = dt;
                repMyShifts.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repMyShifts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repTimes_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <%--<div class="panel-group">--%>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #3A6EA5; color: white">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <%# Eval("Start_Time", "{0:d}") %>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--panel-heading-->
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <p>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblShiftID" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Shift_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Start_Time", "{00:HH:MM}") + " - " + Eval("End_Time", "{00:HH:MM}")%> ' />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# "Job: " + Eval("Job_Type") %>' />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" Text="Make Available" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--col-lg-12-->
                                    </div>
                                    <!--panel-body-->
                                </div>
                                <!--panel-default-->
                                <%--</div>--%>
                                <!--panel-group-->
                            </div>
                            <!--col-lg-12-->
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

This displays a list of all the shifts currently associated with the selected employee.

What I want to appear, is something like a calendar, where the headers would be the days of the week, and below each day would appear any shifts associated with that day (date).

I would also like the user to be able to navigate between different weeks.

Can someone please advise me how to go about creating this calendar?

Comment: why don't you use the **Calendar control** ? and for each day you can check if it's an event day and write the proper code?

Comment: @balexandre The reason I've tried to do it this way is that I was having some difficulty configuring the Calendar control. Is it possible to show time-slots in each day of the calendar control? (I.e. 9:00, 10:00, etc.) Also, would it be possible to show multiple events/shifts on each day?

Comment: @balexandre I don't think you can break down days in a calendar control into hours

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index , kendo UI has a very good scheduler

Comment: @urlreader does that cost money?

Comment: @marc_s I think i've fixed that

Comment: yes, not free, I think.